# Handling multiple IO operations that return optional values

Tags: haskell, optional

The following Haskell code reads a Pandoc document from the DB and then serves it to the user after making a transformation, after the first run it is stored in memory via `IORef State`, inside a `[(String, Pandoc)]` so the document can be quickly looked up again, without hitting the DB or doing the transformation. I don't feel like this code reflects that this is what is happening that well, there is a lot of handling `Maybe`'s that I feel clouds the actual steps that make up this action.

```
module Api.ReadDocument (Route, action) where

import Control.Monad.Reader
import Data.Aeson.Types
import Data.Int
import Data.IORef
import Data.List
import Database.Persist.Postgresql (ConnectionPool, fromSqlKey, runSqlPool)
import Servant
import Servant.Auth.Server
import Text.Pandoc (Pandoc, def, readHtml, writeJSON)
--
import Config
import Queries
import State
import Types.DB
import Types.Pandoc

type Route = "read" :> Capture "id" Int64 :> Get '[JSON] Pandoc

action :: IORef State -> ConnectionPool -> AuthResult Account -> Int64 -> Handler Pandoc
action state pool (Authenticated _) id = viaCache state pool id
action _ _ _ = throwAll err401

viaCache :: IORef State -> ConnectionPool -> Int64 -> Handler Pandoc
viaCache state pool id = do
  let key = show id
  state' <- liftIO $ readIORef state
  maybe (retrieve state pool id) (return . snd) $ find ((== key) . fst) (cached state')

retrieve :: IORef State -> ConnectionPool -> Int64 -> Handler Pandoc
retrieve state pool id = do
  doc <- runSqlPool (Queries.getDocumentFromId id) pool
  maybe (throwError err404) (loadDocument state id) doc

loadDocument :: IORef State -> Int64 -> Document -> Handler Pandoc
loadDocument state id doc = do
  let key = show id
      pd = transform . documentBody $ doc
  _ <- liftIO $ updateState (CacheFile (key, pd)) state
  return pd
```

Previously this was one function, which contained nested case statements like so (pseudo code):

```
action state pool (Authenticated _) id = do
  state' <- fromState state              -- get the state
  case find id state of                  -- find the data
    Just (_, doc) ->
      return doc                         -- return cached document
    Nothing -> do
      doc <- getDocumentFromId id pool   -- get document from db
      case doc of
        Just d -> do
          let doc = performOp $ d        -- perform computation on doc
          _ <- saveToState state doc     -- save the document to in memory cache
          return doc                     -- serve document
        Nothing ->                       -- document not actually in DB
          throwError err404
```

This is obviously much more explicit but I didn't like the nested case statements, and obviously there is a bit more to the code than what I have typed out here.

Answer (score 2):

Here's how your pseudocode can be rewritten with bounded indentation using `MaybeT`.

```
action state pool (Authenticated _) id = cached <|> retrieve <|!> throwError err404 where
  cached = snd <$> MaybeT (find id <$> fromState state)
  retrieve = do 
    doc <- performOp <$> MaybeT (getDocumentFromId id pool)
    _ <- lift $ saveToState state doc
    return doc

infix 2 <|!>
(<|!>) :: Monad m => MaybeT m a -> m a -> m a
mx <|!> y = runMaybeT mx >>= maybe y pure
```

Comment: This is great, and exactly the kind of way I want to re-write my code, it just so happens that both `cache`  and `retrieve` are executed, I want `retrieve` only to run if `cache` fails, is there how would I achieve a similar thing only executing retrieve if cache fails?

Comment: @danbroooks, this is already the case. That is much of the point of `MaybeT`.

Comment: It seems like both are running, I added `_ <- liftIO $ putStrLn "from db: " ++ key` to both functions and they both print to the terminal on each request, which leads me to believe they're both running regardless of each result?

Comment: seems like my `cache` function is always returning `Nothing` so it's not related to the use of `<|>`!